# Definition of Manifold using subspace $\mathcal{S}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading the following definition

> The orthonormal columns of matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ define the basis of the subspace $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Given a point $x$ and $\mathcal{M}$, a manifold is the set
> of all points $x+y$, where $y \in \mathcal{M}$.

Could you please someone explain the intuition of this manifold definition? Is there a formal definition of the manifold where the above one is based?

Comment: Where is this definition from?

Comment: Thanks for the interest, from [here](https://books.google.gr/books?id=wfs-hsrd4WQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) sec 5.1.1

Comment: The object defined here is most often called an *affine subspace* rather than a manifold

Comment: This looks like the definition (of a particular type) of an _affine subspace_, which is an _example_ of a manifold in a more standard sense. If the book you're reading only needs this limited notion it's possible they're using the term _manifold_ in this limited, non-standard sense.

Comment: I know that some texts (e.g. Kato's *Perturbation Theory*) use "linear manifold" to refer to a vector space